# UILabel Text label and timer function issue on table view refresh

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have created a timer function in a subclass of UITableViewCell, which updates the label of itself (the label text) using a timer:

```
 func handleCountdown(){
    if timerIsRunning == false { //check if timer is NOT running, otherwise update timer 
        timerIsRunning = true
        startTime = activity.countdownValue
        runTimer()
    }
}

func runTimer() {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: (#selector(self.updateTimer)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
@objc func updateTimer(){
    let hours = Int(startTime) / 3600
    let minutes = Int(startTime) / 60 % 60

    if startTime > 0 {
        startTime -= 1
        print("The start time for " + String(activity.name) + "is " + String(startTime))
        switch startTime {
        case 0:
            activity.isActive = false
            activity.timerIsRunning = false
            activity.countdownValue = 0
            timer.invalidate()
            activitiesRef = Database.database().reference().child("Users/\(userID)/Activities")
            activitiesRef.child(self.activity.id).setValue([ "id": self.activity.id,
                                                             "name": self.activity.name,
                                                             "isActive": self.activity.isActive,
                                                             "locString": self.activity.locationString,
                                                             "locLat": self.activity.locLat,
                                                             "locLong": self.activity.locLong,
                                                             "privacySetting": self.activity.privacySetting,
                                                             "timerIsRunning": self.activity.timerIsRunning,
                                                             "countdownValue": self.activity.countdownValue])
            returnToInactiveDelegate?.activeToInactive(data: activity)
        case 1..<60: //display seconds
            let count = String(Int(startTime))
            countdownTimer.text = count
            print("The start time for " + String(activity.name) + "is " + String(startTime))

            //countdownTimer.text = String(Int(startTime)) + "s"
        case 60..<3600: //display minutes
            print("The start time for " + String(activity.name) + "is " + String(startTime))

            countdownTimer.text = String(Int(minutes)) + "m"
        case 3600..<86400: // display hours and minutes
            print("The start time for " + String(activity.name) + "is " + String(startTime))

            countdownTimer.text = String(Int(hours)) + "h \(minutes)m"
        default:
            timer.invalidate()
            activity.countdownValue = 0
        }
    }
```

When the timer reaches zero, a delegate function deletes the appropriate cell and moves it to a different section in the table view, as follows:

```
 func activeToInactive(data: Activity) {
    if let i = activeActivities.index(where: { $0.isActive == false }) {
        print("array index to remove: should be where it is NOT active = \(i)")
        activeActivities.remove(at: i)
    }
    inactiveActivities.insert(data, at: 0)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Finally, upon table view reload, it does one last check to see if the timer is still running or not (to see if it should start the timer from the initial start time, or not do anything and let it handle the countdown) as follows:

```
let inactiveCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: inactiveIdentifer , for: indexPath) as! InactiveCell
    let activeCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: activeIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ActiveCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 && self.activeActivities.count != 0  {
        activeCell.name.text = self.activeActivities[indexPath.row].name
        activeCell.location.text = self.activeActivities[indexPath.row].locationString
        activeCell.activity = self.activeActivities[indexPath.row]
        activeCell.returnToInactiveDelegate = self
        if activeCell.activity.isActive == true && activeCell.timerIsRunning == false {
            activeCell.activity.countdownValue = self.activeActivities[indexPath.row].countdownValue
            print(String(self.activeActivities[indexPath.row].countdownValue))
            activeCell.handleCountdown()
        }
        activeCell.countdownTimer.text = String(self.activeActivities[indexPath.row].countdownValue)
        //activeCell.countdownTimer.text = self.activeActivities[indexPath.row].


        return activeCell
```

The issue I am having is that the countdown label text is not updating, despite it showing the correct output in terminal console. My error is repeatable via this example: there are two active activities, with countdowns functioning independently of each other.

`activeActivity[0]` runs to zero, then is handled by case 0 in the ojbc func updateTimer, and passed through the delegate that then deletes it from active and moves it to inactive. The remaining one (what used to be `activeActivity[1]`, is now `activeActivity[0]`) moves "up" in the queue and the timer continues running according to the terminal log, but the countdownLabel.text is stuck at 1s, despite the terminal showing the execution of updateTimer, with it printing the correct start time that SHOULD be displayed in the table view cell.

Comment: Sometimes there are issues with needing to call `tableView.reloadRows(at:with:)` to force the table to redraw the cells and update their contents. I'd be surprised if that's what you need, but give it a try.

Comment: First you should never use a timer method to measure time. It should only be used to update the user interface. Second you don't need to update your UI more than 15/30 times per second, so change your timer repeat interval to something like 1/15 or 1/30 instead of 1/100th of second.

Comment: Second instead of reloading your table view rows to update its content as suggested in the comment above, you should subclass your `UITableViewCell` and add the timer to the cell itself so it wouldn't need to be reloaded to be updated. And about how to measure the time, add a date property to your cell that you initialize with the the end date (the Date it is initialized plus the time interval to finish the countdown). And use the timer method to display the `endDate.timeIntervalSinceNow` in it.

Comment: The timer function is contained in the subclass of UITableViewCell. The timer function still RUNS, it's just not updating the subclassed (custom) tableViewCell. And yea, I'm not going to have the timer update at .01 for shipping, I'm just using that as a test to "simulate" time going quicker so I can check the adding/deleting of the tableViewCells when timer = 0. Can you elaborate on not using a timer to measure time? If I'm understanding you correctly the endDate.timeIntervalSinceNow should be called on tableViewReload and that value set in the cellForRowAtIndexPath override func, correct?