# Update UITableViewCell using Timer without blocking UI

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a UITableView that contains a bunch of cells that count down from a value. Initially I was just running an NSTimer in the ViewController on repeat to run a function that would update the labels and then run a reloadData on the table, and that does technically work, but with some issues.

To fill things in a bit more, I'm well aware NSTimer isn't accurate as a timer, so I use a date calculation for the time on the labels. I also considered using CADisplayLink so the refresh would sync with the screen, but this ran into problems with scrolling the table, making it very jumpy. Another issue is when issuing the Edit command on the table, the UI is unable to delete rows because of the refresh.

So, I've since considered moving my Timer into each UITableViewCell, and I can tell that it is running via the console, but the table doesn't update. This makes sense, given that it can't run the reloadData on the table, but I'm a bit stuck as to where to go next.

I found a [similar thread here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47970719/uilabel-text-label-and-timer-function-issue-on-table-view-refresh) and even tried the [AsyncTimer suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45303189/how-do-i-update-a-uitableview-on-a-timer-while-scrolling) but either I'm doing something wrong, or these aren't quite the same issues? Any help is appreciated, thank you!

```
var timer = Timer()

self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(self.checkTimers), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func checkTimers() {
    for counter in counters {
        if counter.isActive {
            counter.updateSeconds()
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Reloading the entire tableview is very expensive and very disruptive to the view hierarchy. You should only reload the table when there is a major change to the table data. I am not surprised if you have problems doing that every tenth of a second.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49246036/one-timer-per-table-view-cell/49247246#49247246) is an answer that shows how I would approach a tableview of timers; only refresh visible cells

Comment: Thank you!! It was a small tweak but made a huge difference, it's working! It definitely seemed like the table reload was wrong, but I couldn't figure out how to just refresh the cells without issuing a table reload. Sometimes the most obvious answer is the easiest to miss :) Thanks again!